# Piping data to a command

Tags: ruby

In the following, I'm trying to pipe data into a shell command.

```
$ irb
> IO.popen("echo <<EOF", mode="r+") {|io| io.write("hello worldEOF"); io.close_write; result=io.read; }
 => "\n"
```

I would expect the output to be 'hello world'.

How come I get a newline character as output?

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does not read input from stdin. Use `cat`.

```
IO.popen("cat", mode="r+") { |io|
  io.write("hello world\n")
  io.close_write
  result = io.read
}
# => "hello world\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would expect the output to be 'hello world'.

What do you expect the output of the following to be?

```
$ echo <<EOF
> hello world
> EOF
```

(Although, your code doesn't even accomplish that.)

It might be a good idea to make sure your shell command works in a shell before trying to execute it with ruby.

Comment: You're right, I actually did test another command, PlistBuddy, in the shell. Echo was just for the sake of simplicity, but it doesn't make sense in this context. I'll try to make a better example with PlistBuddy